# Can I use a component written in Angular(JS) in AngularDart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html

I would like to use this file uploader in AngularDart. It's written in AngularJS.

https://github.com/agreatfool/Cart/tree/master/dart-version/web/src/bower/angular-file-upload

Is this possible?

Are there examples anywhere of how to do this?

Is there an alternative AngularDart file uploaders I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to combine components of these frameworks, 
except perhaps host a complete Angular Dart app inside Angular TS or vice versa, but still with very limited ways to interact.

Angular Dart was originally generated from Angular TS code until about 2 years ago, but even then this was not supported. Since then they are developed independently and diverted quite a bit more.